# Login test cases failing in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, testing, django-testing, django-tests

Today I am learning to write test cases in Django, and wrote a test case for checking authentication of valid users.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.http import HttpRequest
from aptly_dash.views import newRepo, homePage
from selenium import webdriver
from django.test import Client

class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    #
    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_redirect(self):
        response = self.client.get('/admin/')
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/admin/login/?next=/admin/')

    def test_login(self):
        # Issue a GET request.
        response = self.client.login(username='rakesh', password='ranjan')
        print response
```

I have already created a `username='rakesh'` and `password='ranjan'` but the `response` is coming out be `False`. I am fairly new to writing test cases, and would appreciate if anybody could tell me what is wrong with my `test_login` function. I also want write a test case to check whether django URLs are 403-forbidden to unauthenticated users, and 403-forbidden to authenticated but not staff users. Could anyone point me a good documentation.

Comment: You don't have a user 'rakesh'. Assume your database is blank and everything starts from zero for each test. If you need a user at that point either create it in that test, or in the setUp to have it available on all tests.

Comment: Could you point to any documentation to read about this? Thanks for your comment

Comment: How will you then test that URLs are forbidden for unauthenticated users then? Since everytime we creating new users

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login

Comment: And for unathenticated users, just try accessing them without login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add the user to the setup:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()
    user = User.objects.create_user('rakesh', 'rakesh@rakesh.com', 'ranjan')
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Everytime when you are running the tests, you has a 'new database'.

If you wants log in a user, for execute some tests, you need create him on every TestCase.

> Finally, you’ll need to remember to create user accounts before you
>   can use this method. As we explained above, the test runner is
>   executed using a test database, which contains no users by default. As
>   a result, user accounts that are valid on your production site will
>   not work under test conditions. You’ll need to create users as part of
>   the test suite – either manually (using the Django model API) or with
>   a test fixture. Remember that if you want your test user to have a
>   password, you can’t set the user’s password by setting the password
>   attribute directly – you must use the set_password() function to store
>   a correctly hashed password. Alternatively, you can use the
>   create_user() helper method to create a new user with a correctly
>   hashed password.

Maybe see this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login), can be helpful

Comment: Suppose now I want to test whether authenticated users can access this http://localhost:8000/dashboard? I first need to create a username and password and then go to this url right?

Comment: Because if you just do `self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000/dashboard')` then it will redirect you to admin page.

Comment: Yes, just create the user, login and go to url

Comment: `response = self.client.login(username='rakesh', password='ranjan')
self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000/dashboard')` here my response is True but browser is transferring to the admin page ? How to make tell the server that this is an authenticated user?